# PHP PDO interface with MS SQL Server

Tags: php, sql-server, windows, pdo

I am having trouble with using PHP PDO interface with Microsoft SQL Server. The problem is with converting PHP number values to use in functions of MS SQL Server. I use the following statement to delete certain records:

```
$sql = "DELETE FROM table WHERE SUBSTRING(attribute, 1, ?) = ?";
```

I prepare and execute this statement with code (a little shrinked):

```
$query = $pdo->prepare ($sql);
$query->execute (array (strlen ('Text'), 'Text'));
```

But the query always fails. The error is:

SQLSTATE[42000]: [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Argument data type nvarchar is invalid for argument 3 of substring function.

I am assuming the number from strlen is not parsed into a number, but I don't know how to fix this (except to manually add into the query).

I have found these links, however not very helpful.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqldriverforphp/thread/0f09ac5e-62cd-4ccf-b2cb-848aad23811e

http://drupal.org/node/1169202

The guys on Drupal had same error, but they fixed it with recreating function with casts. Is there any other way to fix this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will solve it, but try something like this

```
$length = strlen('Text');
$text = "Text";

$sql = "DELETE FROM table WHERE SUBSTRING(attribute, 1, :len) = :text";
$query = $pdo->prepare ($sql);
$query->bindParam(':len', $length, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$query->bindParam(':text', $text, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->execute();
```

Comment: Sadly this does not fix the problem. It responds with this error: [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]COUNT field incorrect or syntax error. Either way, I would prefer a solution, that I do not have to rewrite too much code.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$query = $pdo->prepare ($sql);
$query->execute (array ((int) strlen ('Text'), 'Text'));
```

Comment: Sorry, no luck. This displays same error as the problem described in the question. I have also tried a primitve workaround with multiplying the number with 1 or using the function intval.

Comment: I would be surprised if it worked to be honest but I had to add it just in case. It seems to be some sort of casting issue either way, perhaps PDO itself is forcing the variable to be a string by quoting it or something. Did you try casting the value to numeric/integer in the query itself somehow? My experience with MS SQL is limited but I guess this is possible.

Comment: Can you explain more what do you mean? Current solution I have implemented is manually manipulating SUBSTRING function before preparing query. This was the question mark is replaced with the number in the query itself and the thing works. However I am still looking for a better solution.

Comment: I meant something like this query: "DELETE FROM table WHERE SUBSTRING(attribute, 1, CAST(? AS INT)) = ?"; using your existing pdo code.